# Get current directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been developing a small PHP project on my localhost, and in order to do so, I set up an `auto_prepend_file` in the .htaccess file. When I moved this project on to a server, to make it live, I was greeted with an Internal Server Error.

It appears that the file path that I use to get to my desired prepend file is wrong, and I've tried every possible solution that I can think of.

I even made a new page and cleared the htaccess file, so I could `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` and it still wouldn't work when I used the absolute path.

So my question for you is: Is there a way, as far as you know, to grab the current directory, that the htaccess file resides in, and then concatenate the file name on to the end of it, and call it in the `auto_prepend_file` statement?

I am very new to htaccess stuff, so bear this in mind please, I really don't know much about it.

Comment: are you using pathinfo($,PATHINFO_DIRNAME) in your code?

Comment: No, I'm not. It's a strange setup, but it works for me :D

Comment: can you please paste the error from apache error log?

Comment: [Mon May 06 16:36:26 2013] [alert] [client *] /home/pseudeu/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: http://p2p.wrox.com/php-how/34751-how-set-php_value-thru-htaccess.html

Comment: or its being hosted on some crazy OS like windows ..

Comment: I'm running Centos 6, with suPHP. It appears suPHP doesn't allow the 'php_value' command, so I'll have to try something else I guess, does anyone know a work-around?

Comment: why do you need suphp?

Comment: @Cmag the link is dead now..

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find  a work-around.

I am now using a custom php.ini file, which I have declared inside the .htaccess file.

Thanks for all the help guys!